# How to apply a GCC patch in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, patch

I use compiler gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I have found a problem with the compiler which can be solved by applying this following patch https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54930. However, I don't know how to apply this patch file to my gcc? Could someone help me how to do? Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the source of gcc

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2
```

Extract it

```
tar jxvf gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2
```

Install needed dependencies and build tools.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep
```

Get the patch

```
wget https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=28448 -O reorder.patch
```

patch gcc

```
patch < reorder.patch
```

build gcc

```
make
```

and install it, if your are satisfied

```
make install
```

You can read [Building GCC 4.7.0 on Debian Squeeze (Stable)](https://nosemaj.org/debian-gcc-4-7) for more detailed instructions. You can also use the debian package source with the `apt-get source` command.

Comment: @jack279 If your satisfied with my answer you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow.